# Вставить произвольное поле внутри контента

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, acf

Всем привет! Решил попробовать  ACF плагин для wordpress, чтобы выводить произвольные поля на странице. Возник вопрос, мне нужно вставить произвольное поле внутри контента в блок div с каким-то определенным id либо классом, как это сделать?

Например, у меня есть какая-то запись, в ней контент, где-то в контенте есть блок `<div id="custom-field"></div>` как мне вывести контент из acf внутрь этого блока?

Comment: Контент это то что создано в редакторе wordpress? Или какой то собственный контент через код?

Comment: @fortavey да, то, что создано в редакторе  wp

Answer (score 6):

Вставьте в контент шорткод

```
[acf field="field_name"]
```